# Calculate total number of days in a year

Tags: javascript, html

Write javascript function that calculates total number of days for a given year.

```
function daysInMonth(month, year) {
  return new Date(year, month, 0).getDate();
}

var jan = daysInMonth(1, 2016);
var feb = daysInMonth(2, 2016);
var maa = daysInMonth(3, 2016);
var apr = daysInMonth(4, 2016);
var mei = daysInMonth(5, 2016);
var jul = daysInMonth(6, 2016);
var jun = daysInMonth(7, 2016);
var aug = daysInMonth(8, 2016);
var sep = daysInMonth(9, 2016);
var okt = daysInMonth(10, 2016);
var nov = daysInMonth(11, 2016);
var dec = daysInMonth(12, 2016);
var dagen = jan + feb + maa + apr + mei + jul + jun + aug + sep + okt + nov + dec;

document.write('<br> Aantal dagen van jaar 2016 zijn : ' + dagen);
```

but i want to change the year, to 2017 but i dont want to do that 12 times.. how can i do that in 1 time

Comment: Extract it to a variable, then change that. In fact, you appear to *already have the variable*, so maybe just use it?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can find the number of days using the simple leap year algorithem:

> In the Gregorian calendar three criteria must be taken into account to
>   identify leap years: The year can be evenly divided by 4; If the year
>   can be evenly divided by 100, it is NOT a leap year, unless; The year
>   is also evenly divisible by 400. Then it is a leap year.

```js
function daysInYear(year) {
    return ((year % 4 === 0 && year % 100 > 0) || year %400 == 0) ? 366 : 365;
}

console.log(daysInYear(2016));

console.log(daysInYear(2017));
```

**Using loops**

If it's used to teach you loop, you can use a [`for` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) to iterate the 12 months, and calculate the total number of days:

```js
function daysInMonth(month, year) {
  return new Date(year, month, 0).getDate();
}

function daysInYear(year) {
  var days = 0;
  
  for(var month = 1; month <= 12; month++) {
    days += daysInMonth(month, year);
  }
  
  return days;
}

console.log('2016: ', daysInYear(2016));
console.log('2017: ', daysInYear(2017));
```

Comment: Since this Question does not accept new answers. For those reading this Answer: you might consider to let the build-in Date class give the answer for you. Subtracting 2 dates gives the difference in milliseconds. So an alternative to the above: `function daysInYear(year) { return (new Date(year + 1, 0, 1) - new Date(year, 0, 1)) / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24 }` Though calculating yourself can be more fun and educational :-)

Comment: A shorter method to get the days in a given year is as follows: `function daysInYear(year) {
return new Date(year,1,29).getMonth()==1?366:365;
}`